# What is the difference between classes and instances

Tags: class, object, instance

I know what an object is, however I am struggling to understand what classes and instances are.

This below is my own interpretation of what classes and instances. Please can you help me understand what classes and instances and what relationship do they have to each other.

"A class is a blueprint/porotype(idea) and an object is the concrete things(physical thing that you created). An object is an instance of the class( belongs to a particular class)."

I am a beginner trying to learn Object Orientated programming for the first time. Examples also would be appreciated.

Comment: Just follow through with the practical language used for practice exercises. Once creating an instance or two, in code, it should be a “oh duh” moment — and the blueprint analogy will “make sense”.

Answer (score 1):

To get it easily you can think of a class as of a type, and an instance just becomes a variable of the type.

In most C languages you may write `int x = 5;` and that would mean a declaration of variable `x` of type `int`. The same is for classes and objects: you may write `Car myCar = Car();` and that would create a new variable `myCar` (instance) of type (class) `Car`.

Consider also reading more detailed explanation here: https://www.codementor.io/@stevedonovan/class-vs-object-vs-instance-14i2s2lu6r

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a page with a good description of the diference between a class and a object (instance) is [github.com/andrejrs/Object-Oriented-PHP](https://github.com/andrejrs/Object-Oriented-PHP)